# How to make ion-toolbar scollable

Tags: css, ionic4

I'm using Ionic4, I have a page that has two ion-toolbar, the first contains the page title, while the second ( which is pretty long )contains some important data.

I want to fix only the first toolbar, and the second must scroll with the rest of the page.

Here's a screen of the page:

[image]

My Html code..

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar class="header">
  <ion-title class="page-title">
       {{mail.subject}}
    </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
<ion-toolbar class="mail-infos" >
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col> contentts
      </coll>
   </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
 <ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>

 <ion-content> content </ion-content>
```

Comment: Why don't you put the second toolbar inside the `ion-content` instead?

Comment: Now that I read this again I'm wondering if you have misworded what you mean. Are you saying you want that 2x4 button menu in your screenshot to potentially have more icons below it and those icons in a scroll box within that panel? Because the way you worded it sounds like you want the menu to be sticky so when you scroll the page down it stays visible, but now I think again about this that wouldn't make much sense as it covers most (potentially all) of the users screen.